# Keeping the count of the number of times APIs being hit and also provide the number of times it is successful

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, rest

I tried using the spring-boot-starter-actuator dependency, but it is displaying other irrelevant details too.
I tried keeping a static variable but that didn't work as there are many APIs.
Any suggestions/ways to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Counters](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_counters) from [Micrometer](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts) library. It perfectly fits for the case like yours.

Simple example:

```
@Component
public class OrderService {

  private final Counter orderCounter;
  private final Counter abortOrderCounter;

  public OrderService(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
    orderCounter = meterRegistry.counter("order_counter");
    abortOrderCounter = meterRegistry.counter("abort_order_counter");
  }

  public void createOrder() {
   try {
     // logic
     orderCounter.increment();
   } catch (Exception e){
     // abort logic
     abortOrderCounter.increment();
   }      
  }
```

Then, these metrics will be accessible via an endpoint as usual.

Another example [Spring Boot + Micrometer](https://blog.autsoft.hu/defining-custom-metrics-in-a-spring-boot-application-using-micrometer/)